# In IE9 flex property not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-9

My CSS is:

```
.flex_web, .flex_tablet, .flex { display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; }
```

It properly works in chrome, safari and firefox but not work in IE9.

I tried using `display: table` property also ut it not work for me.

I am using angularjs in Cordova.

I want to know if there is any alternative available for flex in ie9.

Thanks

Comment: Isnt flex supported from ie11 up?

Comment: Flex supported from ie11 up but in ie9 it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

flex is supported in IE10+, but IE10 is very buggy and supports only an old specification: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

IE11 has fewer bugs and you can workaround some of them [flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs)

Comment: I know this but I want if there is any alternative for flex in ie9.